# Create ordered array from post id and custom values from post

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a wordpress query that goes through posts with custom post type. I have

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

$post = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($post->have_posts()){
    while ($post->have_posts()){
        $post->the_post();

        $id = get_the_ID();

        $custom = get_post_custom($id);

        $date = $custom["custom_date"][0];

    }
}
```

I need to create an array that will have id as keys and dates for corresponding values something like:

```
Array
(
    [123] => 2014-1-1
    [456] => 2015-2-1
    [789] => 2013-2-8
    [012] => 2011-12-12
)
```

I totally suck at php arrays. I tried by just creating an empty array and then assigning to it values but nothing happened (just got Array out).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
$date_array[$id] = $date;
```

So simple, feels dumb right now xD